# jspdf - last paragraph line is being cut

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, jspdf

I'm using [**jspdf library**](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) for generating PDF file from html. It is really nice one. But I have an issue with last line on each page of the pdf.

Here is a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aidadev/nq361uoz/3/) and my javascript:

```
var pdf = new jsPDF();
$('#generatePdfBtn').click(function () {
    pdf.fromHTML($('#printableContent').html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': 400
    });
    pdf.save('myPdf.pdf');
});
```

When you generate a pdf by clicking on a button, you will see that at the end of the first page we have "pararaph 30" and normally on next page of pdf we should see next "pararaph 31" paragraph. But I don't see it and instead see "pararaph 32". Why last line is being lost? Any ideas please?

Comment: just a thought : why not use print command and then user can select save as pdf.Supported in all browsers. fast and simple. you can let print only printable content.

Comment: I tried, but it is not a good idea as page is not being displayed correctly there.

Comment: did you tried to use @media print css to display only printablecontent and adjusting css values or there was other problem

Comment: yeah, I tried but again there were issues and it would take long time to fix them.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Open your `jspdf.js` or `jspdf.debug.js` local file and modify this:

`this.pdf.internal.getVerticalCoordinateString(this.y), style.color, "Td");`

Erasing `style.color` and save as:

`this.pdf.internal.getVerticalCoordinateString(this.y), "Td");`

Then it runs correctly on firefox and chrome. At least that worked for me and this is a solution until they fix that failure.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is a trick, If you can determine, where you need to put the page break, then you can simply place a `""` there to force it. In this way you can avoid the text from being chopped off.

**Working DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/nq361uoz/4/

Unfortunately, this is a known bug in `jsPDF` which is still in `open` status in the `GitHub` repository.

**More info here:** https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/555

Hope this helps!

Comment: yes I see that it is working if you put "", but in my case I have dynamic content and it can be longer and shorter. I don't know where the page will need to be broken. @David R

Comment: I just found that adding this `<!-- ADD_PAGE -->` also adds a break and content is being moved to next page. But I'm wondering how can I do this in dynamic way. @David R

Answer (score 0):

My guess it cut's the line as it is written not within the margins. Most simple way is to make a loop, that every 31th row is duplicated. Not the best solution, but the quickest.